# Create operator class for pattern matching like text_pattern_ops

Tags: postgresql

I created my own comparison operators on the text datatype that uses natural ordering ('1' < '2' < '10' < '11' etc), using my new operators `#<#`, `#<=#`, `#>#` and `#>=#`.

Now I place them into an operator class to be able to create an index on them, like this:

```
CREATE OPERATOR CLASS text_natsort_ops
   FOR TYPE text USING btree AS
   OPERATOR 1  #<#,
   OPERATOR 2  #<=#,
   OPERATOR 3  =,
   OPERATOR 4  #>=#,
   OPERATOR 5  #>#,
   FUNCTION 1  bttext_natsort_cmp(text, text);
```

However, when I create an index using my new `text_natsort_ops`, this is not used in queries involving `like` as it is done when the `text_pattern_ops` are used.

How do I declare my operator class to allow `like` to use my index?

**UPDATE:**

The above seems to work, so the question is invalid. My real problem was that I used a query like:

```
select *
  from mytable
 where number like 'edi%'
 order by number using #<#
 limit 10
```

and I also had another index using text_pattern_ops, which was choosen by the planner because it seems to work much faster. However, because of the `order by ... using` only the index using my new ops will be useful... the other index returns too many results, and I need the limit clause to be available to the index scan.

Comment: You should post your update as answer, so this Q doesn't lurk as "unanswered".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above seems to work, so the question is invalid. My real problem was that I used a query like:

```
select *
  from mytable
 where number like 'edi%'
 order by number using #<#
 limit 10
```

and I also had another index using text_pattern_ops, which was choosen by the planner because it seems to work much faster. However, because of the order by ... using only the index using my new ops will be useful... the other index returns too many results, and I need the limit clause to be available to the index scan.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the PostgreSQL Prefix extension at https://github.com/dimitri/prefix
They, too, define their own *OPERATOR CLASS* and tell PostgreSQL to use special GIST indexes for certain operators, Maybe you need something similar?

```
CREATE OPERATOR CLASS gist_prefix_range_ops DEFAULT FOR TYPE prefix_range USING gist ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible.  You have to think about what you are doing and why this won't work.  Either you will have an index which supports a prefix search or something which supports a natural number range search.  You can't have a btree index which supports both.

Consider something like:

```
SELECT * FROM foo
WHERE bar like '10%'
ORDER BY bar USING #>#;
```

Your problem is that your two indexes will not have an order that will match.  The index for use with LIKE will go 101, 101000, 101001, etc.  while the index for your ordering will go 10, 11, 12, 13... 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, ...

Because your ordering requires different search order there is no way to use the same index for both.  At some point if PostgreSQL allows physical order searches of indexes this might become possible but as long as indexes are logical order only I don't think this can work.